# Show header for multiple groups in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am working on SSRS report and have the data as below which comes from one stored procedure.

```
Group     InitialName Value Section
Group     A           1000  1
Group     B           2000  1
Group     C           3000  1
Test1G1   All         300   2
Test1G2   A           200   2
Test1G3   B           100   2
Test2G1   All         300   3
Test2G2   A           200   3
Test2G3   B           100   3
```

If we see the above data, we have 3 different section and I want to add the header for each section like this:

```
Group     InitialName Value Section
Group     A           1000  1
Group     B           2000  1
Group     C           3000  1

Group1    InitialName Value Section
Test1G1   All         300   2
Test1G2   A           200   2
Test1G3   B           100   2

Group2    InitialName Value Section
Test2G1   All         300   3
Test2G2   A           200   3
Test2G3   B           100   3
```

How can I show the header for each section in ssrs?

Answer (score 0):

Two different ways of approaching this.

You can put your header inside the group like this..
[image: HeaderInsideGroup]

The large row group you can see would be the thing you want to repeat on.

Or you can put the tablix inside a list, like this:
[image: TablixInsideList]

The row group for the list would be the same as the row group in the example above.

Each of these will do what you want - I personally favour the list method, but I like using lists.

More information on lists in SSRS: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/microsoft_in_education/2013/03/09/ssrs-using-a-list-item-to-display-details/

Comment: thanks for you answer, I will follow the same and let you know the result.